# Can't find SDK folder inside Android studio path, and SDK manager not opening

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, path, android-sdk-manager

I have installed Android Studio for the millionth time but when i go to C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio , i can't find any folder named "SDK" , can't find it any where on the computer either.
Also, the SDK manager doesn't open, which i guess is a problem linked to the first one.

Answer (score 39):

**If you have downloaded the AS + SDK bundle:**

> Assuming the defaults were left unchanged, you will find the SDK in
>   `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Android`

If it is missing at this location, one of the following reasons apply: you have chosen a custom location, you missed to install the SDK at all, or (unlikely) they have changed the default install location.

Note #1: the `AppData` directory is hidden by default. If you have a standard Windows configuration, the `C:\` path above should work "as is" (hit Win + R -> paste the path -> Enter).

Note #2: you will never find the SDK in the Android Studio directory unless you have explicitly put it in there. The reason is that those directories might be deleted after installing a newer version of Android Studio and you would have to re-install the SDK as well.

**If you have retrieved the standalone SDK by some other means:**

The SDK location may vary (from my experience), however (assuming the default configuration) you will most likely find it in `C:\Program Files\Android` or `C:\Users\%USERNAME%`

Comment: This is where mine was. But, on Earth, why?

Answer (score 14):

If you don't have it at C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Android (this is where most people have it) than it is possible you don't have it installed. Go to Tools > Android > SDK Manager and then click on "Android SDK." On the top of the SDK Manager it will list the SDK Location. Click edit. If you don't have Android SDK installed, it will give you the option to install it in certain location. Install it, and Android Studio should work!

Comment: You said "than" not "then" :)

Answer (score 13):

Tools > Android > SDK Manager > there you'll see the path to SDK

Answer (score 6):

SDK folder by defalut is in `C:\Users\<user-name>\AppData\Local\Android`. And the AppData folder is hidden in windows. Enable show hidden files in folder option, and give a look inside that.

Answer (score 4):

I had to open Android studio and go through the wizard. Android studio will install the SDK for you.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure all the folders are visible.
click start>control panel>Appearance and Personalization>Show hidden files and folders  then click "Show hidden files, folders and drives"
The file should be in C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Android as mentioned above. otherwise you can check by opening Android SDK Manager - top left under SDK path.

Answer (score 3):

If SDK folder is present in system, one can find in C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Android

If Android/SDK folder is not found
Once done with downloading and installing Android Studio, you need to launch studio.
On launching Android studio for the first time, we get option to download further more components, in that we have SDK. 
On downloading components one can find SDK under Appdata (C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Android)

Answer (score 2):

If your are using android studio go to file >> project structure on the left pane press on SDK location . you will find the path where your sdk is located

Answer (score 2):

When you install the android studio just by downloading from https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html sometimes sdk folder will not get appear in C:\Users\home\AppData\Local\Android Location..
But to set the android studio we need to set the path for android on this location.
So simply
1) start the android setup.
2) follow the instruction and android studio will automatically download the sdk folder by itself. (it will show the window like "Downloading Components").
After completing that installation check the above path again. 
sdk folder will get appear now.

Comment: Yes, after installing latest Studio (v3.1.2). 64-bit, on Win-10, and bringing it up first time, it complained that it couldn't find its SDK. It explicitly says to NOT continue on without first resolving the problem. So, IGNORE that warning, because when you DO continue on, the first think it does is allow you to let it download and install the SDK.  (Come on, Google...make up your mind.)

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. And I am able to resolve it by uninstalling the previous version I had, and removing the Android studio projects and reinstalling it.

And then go to Settings-> Android Studio -> Click on edit, to specify studio location, it will recognize the requask you if you would like to download sdk,

Answer (score 0):

So I was trying to root one of my old phones and process required Android SDK. When I searched Android SDK, all i could do was download and install Android Studio. Everything went fine and smooth, till I tried to look for SDK in installation. I could not find it under Android Studio installation. But after a little search on Google and Android Studio configuration on my computer, I was able to find it at

```
        C:\Users\username\Android\sdk
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found it in /Users//Library/Android/sdk

Answer (score 0):

For me it was :

```
C:\Users\{your-user-name}\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

After installation if you get a message about Proxy, it means that you're probably behind a firewall. You can create a new Outgoing firewall rule to include it. Add this to Allow:

C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\studio64.exe

It will then download required SDK components

Once that's done, SDK will be in:
C:\Users\your_user_name\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

Answer (score 0):

**For anyone who really can't find the SDK, you can manually download it from android studio.**

File => Settings => Appearance & Behavior => System Settings => Android SDK

If you do not have a SDK (or did not select the right folder), you will be asked to select the SDK version and the folder where the SDK will be installed.

This is how I fixed by SDK not found problem.

Answer (score -1):

`C:\Users\*********\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`

Check whether the `USERNAME` is correct, for me a new `USERNAME` got created with my proxy extension.

Answer (score -1):

**System: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS**, yet you can try these steps in accordance to your respective systems.

If there is an SDK file present, it should be most likely found at `/home/USERNAME/Android/sdk`

`USERNAME` is to be replaced by your username

If there is none, check the specified sdk path for the project in android studio.
`File > Project Structure > sdk path`

The sdk directory should be present in the specified path. In case, it is not there, open the file:
`PROJECT_DIRECTORY/android/local.properties`

`PROJECT_DIRECTORY` needs to be replaced by your project name.

If the file is not there, create it.
Then add the following line depending on where you find the sdk directory.

If sdk is there at `/home/USERNAME/Android/`:
add the line: `sdk.dir = /home/tanya/Android/sdk`

If sdk is **not** there at `/home/USERNAME/Android/`:
add the line: `sdk.dir = /home/tanya/Android/`

If the path specified for sdk directory in '**Project Structure**' is entirely different and the sdk directory is present at the specified location,
add the line: `sdk.dir = SPECIFIED_SDK_PATH`

Add the specified sdk path in place of `SPECIFIED_SDK_PATH`

Comment: @Paul It's nice of you to try to filter out relevant material for other developers. Although, the work around was implemented on Ubuntu but as mentioned above, if similar steps in accordance to the system used, including Windows, are performed the error might solve in certain cases.