# Not being able to access /data/data/com.your.packagename/databases/your.databasename folder on an android studio emulator

Tags: android

There are many posts saying how to access the /data/data/com.your.packagename/databases/your.databasename
 folder by using an emulator or rooting your phone. However, I am using an emulator and I am still not able to access the /data/data/com.your.packagename/databases/your.databasename
folder in the android device manager. See picture below (click on android device manager) where I accessed the ADM --> went to my application (com.bartboersma.myfootballapplication) but could not open the data folder (it appears to be empty but after reading only it seems that access is not granted).

How come?

[image: Andrdoid Device Manager]

Comment: I don't have /data/data/databases folder on my phone or emulator. /data/data has data from installed apps[.](http://android-app-promotion.com/) Why do you expect /data/data/databases?

Comment: the data/data/com.your.packagename/databases/your.databasename folder in the android device manager (see picture)

Comment: I don't see any picture. EDIT: You want to enclose your links like this: [link-text](uri)

Comment: Have you tried running the console? Something like this: `adb shell`, `run-as com.bartboersma.myfootballapplication`, `cd /data/data/com.your.packagename/databases`, `ls`

Comment: Try typing `adb root` in your terminal and see if it changes anything for you.

Comment: How do I do this? Is there a link where this is explained?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by doing the following:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/31137694/7971387 so I could locate the platform-tools map and all in it.
2. Next up I followed these steps: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/82271
3. Lastly, I typed this into the terminal: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40097307/7971387

That granted me access to the data/data/com.your.packagename/databases/your.databasename

picture: [Picturing showing access to data\data folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUVKb.png)

Thanks guys for all the responses