# Android Studio is unable to find Android SDK

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I have downloaded the latest version of Android 3.0.1.0 along with the command line sdk tools. I unzipped both the files and tried to install Android Studion but it doesn't find SDK. After searching online I put unzipped SDK folder into the following directory C:\Users\User-Name\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk, but it still doesn't find it.I have also heard that Android Studio contains SDk tools but still it is showing no SDK tools.Please help me.I am using windows 7 32-bit OS.

Comment: SDK shouldn't be zipped. Extract it. This should help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581752/android-studio-how-to-change-android-sdk-path

Comment: look into this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29099636/cant-find-sdk-folder-inside-android-studio-path-and-sdk-manager-not-opening

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio go to:

`File → Settings → Appearance & Behaviour → System Settings → Android SDK`

and set the location of your SDK

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The real problem was diacritics in my user home folder in windows! (C:\Users\Rodiče).

So I renamed it (here are the steps:
https://superuser.com/questions/890812/how-to-rename-the-user-folder-in-windows-10)

and then make symlink (for possible applications which uses the old path):

```
mklink /J "c:\Users\Rodice\" "c:\Users\Rodiče\"
```